# How do I plot an asymptote

Tags: python, numpy

Hi I'm new to code and trying to plot an asymptote at `y=x` in python where my y and x are both functions

```
import NumPy as np
#define t

t=np.linspace(0.1,10,1000)

#define x

x=(4/3)*t+(np.cos(13*t))/t

#define y

y=(4/3)*t+(np.sin(13*t))/t

#imprort mat plot

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#plot the graphs
plt.plot(x,y,'g--')

#make the graph look nice
plt.title('x(t) versus y(t)')

plt.xlabel('x(t)')

plt.ylabel('y(t)')
```

How would I plot an asymptote for this curve where `y=x`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to plot a `y=x` line then this will do

```
plt.plot(x,x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed `plt.show()`

```
import numpy as np
t=np.linspace(0.1,10,1000)

#define x

x=(4/3)*t+(np.cos(13*t))/t

#define y

y=(4/3)*t+(np.sin(13*t))/t

#imprort mat plot

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#plot the graphs
plt.plot(x,x,'g--')

#make the graph look nice
plt.title('x(t) versus y(t)')

plt.xlabel('x(t)')

plt.ylabel('y(t)')
plt.show()
```